# How can I verify nginx-unprivileged Docker image is run with non-root user?

Tags: docker, nginx

I've been trying to run my applications with non-root users in docker containers. One such application is a static web page served by nginx. I originally used the [nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) as the base for my docker image. However, in one of the sections it specifies an [image that runs with an unprivileged user](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged).

My nginx configuration originally listens to `port 80`, however but based on the image description, I had expected either my nginx to listen on port 8080 within the container or for the container's port 8080 to be exposed.

But testing both leaves me confused because neither allows me to connect. Instead my port 80 is still accessible. I understand that port 80 is a restricted port that does not normally allow access other than from the root user. I wanted to run either `ps aux` or `netstat` in order to check the settings in my container, but neither is available from the base container image and as I am no longer `root` I cannot install them.

So my question is this:
How can I verify that the nginx-unprivileged image is truly run as an unprivileged user?

Comment: `docker exec -it -u root your_running_container_name bash` then help yourself (replace `bash` with whatever shell is available in your image if needed).

Comment: @Zeitounator I can access the shell on my image, but it doesn't change that I cannot install any of the tools I need to verify. The image starts with nginx user instead of root user.

Comment: The command I gave you lets you access a shell inside your running container as root...

Comment: @Zeitounator, ah sorry, I misread the line. Thank you that worked.